# Show google analytics report of my website in localhost html

Tags: html, google-analytics, localhost

Is that possible to display google analytics report in html page which is in localhost (wamp).
I created a google analytics for one website and get a tracking id like UI-XXXXXX-XX. created an html page using google provided script.But the page showing as blank page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container"></div>
<script>

gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  /**
   * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
   * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
   * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
   */
  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'UA-xxxxxxx-1',
  });


  /**
   * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
   * element with the id "view-selector-container".
   */
  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector-container'
  });

  // Render the view selector to the page.
  viewSelector.execute();


  /**
   * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
   * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
   * with the id "chart-container".
   */
  var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:date',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday'
    },
    chart: {
      container: 'chart-container',
      type: 'LINE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
  });


  /**
   * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
   */
  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    dataChart.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
  });

});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need a public callback address for OAuth to work, so I don't think this will work on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that yes, it is possible.

You have to modify a few things, like

- the `clientid: 'UA-xxxxxxx-1'`, is not the profile id, it is the client id, which you obtain after you create an account on [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
- in the google developer console you'll have to whitelist some callback urls for the oauth. I don't think http://localhost.localdomain/... can be added, but, you can modify your /etc/hosts file **and alias any domain you want** with your localhost.

Although the answer comes too late for you, I hope others will find this useful